# How do Statistica's %75 and %25 Data Sampling & 10 fold Cross Validation works together?

Tags: validation, svm

I made an analysis on some data using Dell's Statistica software. I am using this analysis in a scientific paper. Although data mining is not my primary topic I took Data Mining class before and have some knowledge.

I know that data is either separated as %75 %25 (numbers may change) training and test parts or n fold cross validation is used to test the model performance.

In Statistica SVM modeling prior to execution of model there are tabs to make configurations. In data sampling tab I entered %75, %25 separation and in cross-validation tab I entered 10 -fold cross validation. In the output, I see that the data was actually separated as training and test (model predictions are given for test values).

There is also a cross-validation error. I will copy results below. I have difficulty in the understanding and in the interpretation of this output. I hope someone who know better statistics compared to me and/or who is more experienced to this tools may explain how it works to me?

Ferda

> Support Vector machine results                      SVM type:
>   Regression type 1 (capacity=9.000, epsilon=0.100)    Kernel type:
>   Radial Basis Function (gamma=0.053)    Number of support vectors = 705
>   (674 bounded)      Cross-validation error = 0.244
>                                                         Mean error squared = 1.830(Train), 0.193(Test), 1.267(Overall)    S.D. ratio =
>   0.952(Train), 37076026627971.336(Test), 0.977(Overall)    Correlation coefficient = 0.314(Train),  -0.000(Test),  0.272(Overall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Statistica website has an answer for my misunderstanding. In Sampling tab data may be separated into training and test sets and in cross- validation tab, if for example 10 is selected then 10-fold cross validation is used to decide the proper ni, epsilon etc. like SVM parameters for the execution of the SVM modeling.

This explanation cleared out my problem. I hope it helps to people in similar situations...

Ferda